# R studio - обозначения

Tags: r

Что значат следующие обозначения в R Studio?

```
!!
!!!
-!! (пример, mutate(!!col := coalesce(!!col.new, !!col)))
:=
```

Comment: Где такие обозначения встретились?

Answer (score 0):

Восклицательные знаки нужны для quasi-quotation, см. [здесь](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html)

`:=`, вроде бы, из синтаксиса `data.table`; нужен для создания новой переменной. Пример:

```
library(data.table)
data <- mtcars
setDT(data)
data[, new_variable := mpg + wt, by = cyl]

head(data)
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb new_variable
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4       23.620
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4       23.875
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1       25.120
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1       24.615
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2       22.140
6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1       21.560
```